# How to get/access subdomain name in code

Tags: magento2, access, subdomain

How to get or access subdomain name in code.
Magento verion 2.3

Comment: What is your sub-domain & what is the domain of your Magento (domain through which you can access your Magento) & where you want to get the URL can you please elaborate?